# 'ip netns exec' command execution using nsid obtained from 'ip netns list-id'

Tags: networking, ip, network-interface, iproute

I have previously used `ip netns exec` command to modify netns interfaces. But if there is no name associated with a netns (eg: docker), how can I use `nsid` result of `ip netns list-id` command for modifying the netns interface.

Comment: The answer to this question with small example: https://lwn.net/Articles/612866/

Comment: https://lwn.net/Articles/612866/  doesnt give any answer. it  descibes just propositions that has never come to real life.

Answer (score 4):

You have to find parent process id for all nsid, the only way how to do that I know, is to check all the `/proc/[0-9]*/ns/net` as mentioned here https://serverfault.com/a/900972/205043

```bsh
# Create netns directory if not exist
mkdir -p /var/run/netns

# Add all process namespaces to netns
for i in /proc/[0-9]*/ns/net; do
  ln -s $i /var/run/netns/proc$(echo $i | cut -d/ -f3)
done

# Remove unassociated network namespaces
for i in $(ip netns | grep ^proc | grep -v id); do
  rm -f /var/run/netns/${i}
done

# Remove children processes
for i in $(ip netns | grep ^proc | awk 'a[$3]++ {print $1}'); do
  rm -f /var/run/netns/${i}
done

# Do some action for each ns (eg. check if there is 1.2.3.4 address exists)
for i in $(ip netns | grep ^proc | awk '{print $1}'); do
  echo -n "$i "
  ip netns exec $i ip addr | grep -c '1.2.3.4'
done

# Remove added namespaces
rm -f /var/run/netns/proc*
```

In my case newly added nsids looks like:

```
ip netns list-id
nsid 0 (iproute2 netns name: proc26847)
nsid 1 (iproute2 netns name: proc29068)
nsid 2 (iproute2 netns name: proc27483)
nsid 3 (iproute2 netns name: proc27644)
nsid 7 (iproute2 netns name: proc30377)
nsid 9 (iproute2 netns name: proc9606)
nsid 10 (iproute2 netns name: proc15587)
nsid 11 (iproute2 netns name: proc28395)
nsid 12 (iproute2 netns name: proc30729)
nsid 13 (iproute2 netns name: proc29702)
nsid 14 (iproute2 netns name: proc30060)
nsid 15 (iproute2 netns name: proc31698)
nsid 16 (iproute2 netns name: proc3309)
nsid 17 (iproute2 netns name: proc28934)
nsid 18 (iproute2 netns name: proc21272)
nsid 19 (iproute2 netns name: proc921)
nsid 21 (iproute2 netns name: proc32718)
nsid 26 (iproute2 netns name: proc5864)
```

Comment: very big thank you